# Derivative of natural logarithm

Tags: derivatives

Question: $f(x) = (\ln x)^{\ln x} $

I'm rewriting it as $\ln(e^{(\ln x) (\ln x)}) $ Since $e^{\ln x}  = x$

$d/dx = 1/e^{\ln^2x} \times d/dx (e^{\ln^2x})$

Is this correct?

I just wanna know if this is the right step to take before I start differentiating.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $x^x$? If so, it might be easier to just use the chain rule for $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}u^u\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(x)$.

Comment: No.  $\ln (e^{(\ln x)(\ln x)} = (\ln x)(\ln x)\ne (\ln x)^{\ln x}$.  You mean $\ln e^{(\ln x)^{\ln x}}$.  Note $(a^b)^c \ne a^{(b^c)}$.

Answer (score 1):

No - you cannot pull the power inside the log like that since $(\ln x)^{\ln x}\neq\ln (x^{\ln x})$.

However, you can write
$$(\ln x)^{\ln x} = e^{\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))}.$$

Now you can use the chain and product rules to differentiate. You can show
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x)))=\frac{\ln(\ln(x))+1}{x}$$
and hence
$$\frac{d}{dx}{(\ln x)^{\ln x}}=\frac{\ln(\ln(x))+1}{x}e^{\ln(x)\ln(\ln(x))}=\frac{\ln(\ln(x))+1}{x}(\ln x)^{\ln x}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Your rewriting isn't correct. Actually
$$(\ln x)^{\ln x}=\mathrm e^{\ln x\cdot\ln(\ln x)}$$
so
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\Bigl(\frac1x\,\ln(\ln x)+\ln x\frac1{x\ln x}\Bigr)\mathrm e^{\ln x\cdot\ln(\ln x)}\\
&=\frac{\ln(\ln x)+1}{x}\ln x^{\mkern 2mu\ln x}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Use $f(x) = \exp(\ln x \cdot \ln\ln x).$

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, you get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
( \ln x) ^{\ln x} =( \ln e^{ \ln x})^{\ln x}
\end{eqnarray*}
and this does not make differntiiating the expresion any easier.

To differnetiate let $y= (\ln x)^{\ln x}$, take logarithms of this and implicitly differentiate (use the product rule on the RHS)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln y= ( \ln x) \ln (\ln x) \\
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{ \ln (\ln x)}{x} + \frac{ \ln x}{x \ln x }.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply by $y$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{dy}{dx}= \left( \frac{ \ln (\ln x)+1 }{x} \right) ( \ln x) ^{\ln x}.
\end{eqnarray*}